# Does a smaller cluster size increase the ratio of NTFS compression?

Tags: filesystems, ntfs, compression

I read that NTFS compression needs a partition formatted with an allocation unit size <= 4KB.

Could a smaller cluster size of a partition give more compression and lessen wasted space? For example, a cluster size of 512 bytes instead of 4 KB?

Comment: blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2008/05/20/…Good link, Can indeed use smaller clusters, but what would be so small generally now that such tiny clusters would be usefull?  Be sure to read 2nd to last paragraph of the link after you scan over the stuff you already know.

Comment: I want the lowest wasted space and maintain the highest compression possible.

Comment: @Psycogeek: your link is error. Please edit it

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2008/05/20/understanding-ntfs-compression.aspx